# IF function over a selection of cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am having a problem using an `IF` function to detect a character in a group of cells.

I want to detect a 'N' which is created by another `IF` function to mark a cell for rejection.

Currently I am able to make it work on one cell by using the formula:

- `=IF(Y16="N","X"," ")`

I tried using the below, but had no luck:

- `=IF(Y16:AD26="N","X"," ")`

However this brings `#VALUE!` error

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also try `=IF(COUNTIF(Y16:AD26,"H"),"X","")`